# How to perform authorization in RESTful requests with angularjs?

Tags: rest, angularjs, restful-authentication

I am using angularjs to make REST requests to an API that requires authorisation.  The authorisation requires that the request is signed (similar to Amazon s3) and that this signature is sent in the headers.

I am unsure how to do this securely with angularjs.  As this is client side the credentials need to be embedded in the js code which exposes a massive security hole.

I assume I'm missing something obvious here? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you aren't missing anything. I think possible solution here is write your own authorization backend that will hold your credentials and will return token to your application.

Comment: That sounds close to a workable solution, it keeps the credentials out of the visible application.  Though what is to stop a request being forged for signing to the backend?  IP restrictions?

Comment: To properly answer on your question, you should add more data about what kind of authorization is used at your service.

Security measures that you should take depends on what kind of request signing is used in your service. You gave as example Amazon S3, which should not be accessed from vulnerable code.  Frontend code is vulnerable. If any request to your service requires to be signed with "master" credentials, you should proxy all of them.